# forall notation: what does the period / dot mean?

Tags: haskell, purescript

What does the period / dot mean?

```
forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Is it merely a separator?

Comment: “Is it merely a separator?” Yes.

Comment: And a low precedence one at that. Better than having to parenthesize all the stuff after it....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's just a syntactic separator. It separates variable declarations from variable usages, just like the `->` in a lambda expression. It means "Here endeth the binders". I suppose the language designers went for `.` because it's 22 characters shorter.

Comment: The other usual notations in mathematics are rather annoying for programming: `forall a (Num a => a -> a -> a)` and `forall a : Num a => a -> a -> a`. This leaves us with `.`.

Comment: @rightfold `:` wouldn't have been that bad, I suppose

Comment: @M.Walker Many mathematicians do as well. The problem is that, in type theory, programming languages theory (and category theory to some extent), we write a lot of "forall x:T, y:A->B, ...". Writing "forall x:T: p(x)" looks strange. Historically a trend formed to write "forall x:T. p(x)", perhaps borrowing the "dot" separator from lambda calculus. (I don't know who started that, though -- Peano/Russell used dots, but differently.) Haskell followed that trend (but without commas). In CS papers, I often see dots, but other notations are used as well.